# PowerShell Compare-Object filtering

Tags: arrays, powershell, filter, compare

Attempting to filter files from two source locations and one destination. All 3 contain files and are very mismatched.

All files in locations correctly get pulled using:

```
$Source1Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source1 -File -Recursive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {($_.Extension -ne ",txt") -and ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $False)}
$Source2Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source2 -File -Recursive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {($_.Extension -ne ",txt") -and ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $False)}
$DestFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Dest -File -Recursive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {($_.Extension -ne ",txt") -and ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $False)}
```

Now that each array has the files, I want to filter only grabbing the newest files to be eventually copied to the destination. Additionally filter out all files that are the newest or newer at the destination.

So far my solution has been this, but it keeps grabbing the older files, but it IS filtering all the files that are the same.

```
$S1files = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject @($Source1Files | Select-Obect) -DifferenceObject @($DestFiles | Select-Object) -Property LastWriteTime -PassThru | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}
$S2files = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject @($Source2Files | Select-Obect) -DifferenceObject @($DestFiles | Select-Object) -Property LastWriteTime -PassThru | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}
```

The above is where the hang-up is. Then I would compare them to each other to only have the newest files left that are not already on the destination.

My thought is $S1files will ONLY have the files from the source that are newer than destination. Same with $S2files.

Adding replies:

Sorry for all the typos. I was trying to retype it from another network quickly. It is sort of a file sync, but it's folder-specific at a time. There are too many TBs of information to do full syncs. So, it targets anywhere from 1-50 files at a time typically. It creates the folder structure and everything at the destination as well, which is important since the destination does not look exactly the same. That all works pretty flawlessly. The files are anywhere from 3mb to 500gb, more so in the 100gb range. So excessive copying is attempting to be prevented.

To answer some questions, Select-Object is used specifically because there are times when there are empty arrays, which would cause errors.

This is a file update script. The files on the destination come in 3 ways; not there, older, the same (newest). Each source as well as the same 3 ways. Don't even get me started on how much it is a waste to keep the older data, that is another topic that is to be addressed later. The files get put on a source. Then they get transferred to the destination. Sometimes at the destination, they are QA/QC and determined they need to be redone. So a file with the same name is put on a source. This is normally 6 months or so apart.

Robocopy how you are thinking doesn't work. Because of how it is written, it also checks the files 1 to 1. Additionally, you may NEVER see it. Robocopy can break Qtree. I have seen it twice now, and that requires completely deleting and remaking the share, and entire folder structure and files.

I am not not sure how to make the change to check, but is the LastWriteTime the issue in $S1files ? The normal LastWriteTime looks like MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm. Does it need to be changed to yyyyMMddHHmm and THEN comapred?

Comment: `,txt` is unlikely to match real-world extensions - I assume you meant `.txt`. If you've constrained `Get-ChildItem`'s output with `-File`, you needn't check for `$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False` later. `Select-Obect` should be `Select-Object`, but note that its use without arguments is an effective no-op.

Comment: Is this basically a file sync script? I.e you want to copy any *missing* files from two sources into a destination? Using the ```LastWriteTime``` to identify “missing” files would be problematic as it’s not a “key” property - you could have more than one file with the same “last write time” and then your sync will get screwy. If you can clarify what you mean by “grabbing the newest files” it would help…

Comment: Sorry for all the typos. I was trying to retype it from another network quickly. It is sort of a file sync, but it's folder-specific at a time. There are too many TBs of information to do full syncs. So, it targets anywhere from 1-50 files at a time typically. It creates the folder structure and everything at the destination as well, which is important since the destination does not look exactly the same. That all works pretty flawlessly. 

The files are anywhere from 3mb to 500gb, more so in the 100gb range. So excessive copying is attempting to be prevented.

Comment: To answer some questions, Select-Object is used specifically because there are times when there are empty arrays, which would cause errors.

Comment: This is a file update script. The files on the destination come in 3 ways; not there, older, the same (newest). Each source as well as the same 3 ways. Don't even get me started on how much it is a waste to keep the older data, that is another topic that is to be addressed later. 

The files get put on a source. Then they get transferred to the destination. Sometimes at the destination, they are QA/QC and determined they need to be redone. So a file with the same name is put on a source. This is normally 6 months or so apart.

Comment: Without the -passthru and including the name property, it would return the older file.  Maybe robocopy is a better tool for this.

Comment: Robocopy how you are thinking doesn't work. Because of how it is written, it also checks the files 1 to 1. Additionally, you may NEVER see it. Robocopy can break Qtree. I have seen it twice now, and that requires completely deleting and remaking the share, and entire folder structure and files.

Comment: I am not not sure how to make the change to check, but is the LastWriteTime the issue in $S1files ? The normal LastWriteTime looks like MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm. Does it need to be changed to yyyyMMddHHmm and THEN comapred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You're trying to compare `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances as output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) by their `.LastWriteItem` property values only (`-Property LastWriteTime`), which isn't sufficient.
- Instead, you want to compare them by their *relative paths* first, and *then* by last write time.
- For the intended comparison, you'll need to use a [*calculated*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) property<sup>[1]</sup> with `-Property` in order to dynamically determine the *relative path* of each input file object, as shown below.

---

```bash
# Get the 3 collections of files.
$Source1Files, $Source2Files, $DestFiles = 
  $Source1, $Source2, $Dest | 
    ForEach-Object {
      # Note: The unary form of "," outputs the Get-ChildItem results
      #       as a single object (array).
      , (Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Exclude *.txt)
    }

# Get the full root paths, with trailing separators.
# These will be used in the calculated property passed to Compare-Object
# for deriving the relative paths of the input objects.
$fullRootPaths = 
  $Source1, $Source2, $Dest | 
  Convert-Path | 
  ForEach-Object { $_ + [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar }

# Use a calculated property to compare by relative paths.
$S1files, $S2files =
  $Source1Files, $Source2Files | 
  ForEach-Object {
    , (
      Compare-Object -PassThru $_ $DestFiles -Property {
        # Find the applicable root path and remove it from the
        # full file path to yield the relative path.
        foreach ($root in $fullRootPaths) {
          if ($_.FullName.StartsWith($root, 'OrdinalIgnoreCase')) {
            return $_.FullName.Substring($root.Length)
          }
        }
      }, LastWriteTime  | 
      Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='
    )
  }
```

---

**Update**: You later stated the following requirements:

- It is sufficient to compare files by *name only*, given that in each directory file names are guaranteed to be unique.
- You want your results limited to:

  - files from each *source* directory only, assuming that they:
  - either: exist in the source directory only
  - or: if they are *newer* than their destination counterpart.

To that end, you can use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) instead of `Compare-Object`:

```bash
# Get the full path of the destination directory.
$destRootPath = (Convert-Path $Dest) + [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar

$S1files, $S2files =
  $Source1Files, $Source2Files | 
  ForEach-Object {
    , (
      & { $_; $DestFiles } | Group-Object -Property Name |
        ForEach-Object {
          $firstFileIsFromDest = $_.Group[0].FullName.StartsWith($destRootPath, 'OrdinalIgnoreCase')
          if ($_.Count -eq 1) {
            # File exist only in one collection.
            # Only output it if it is from the source file collection
            if (-not $firstFileIsFromDest) {
              return $_.Group[0]
            }
          } else {
            # File exists in both collections.
            # Only output it if the one from the source file collection is newer.
            $otherFileIsNewer = $_.Group[1].LastWriteTime -gt $_.Group[0].LastWriteTime
            if ($firstFileIsFromDest -and $otherFileIsNewer) {
              return $_.Group[1]
            }
          }
        }
    )
  }
```

**Alternatively** (no code shown), *assuming that files with the same names are in the same relative position in the directory subtrees being compared*:

- Iterate over the source directories only, and for each, look for a counterpart in the destination directory, using the same relative path
- Include the source file at hand in the output if either no counterpart exists or if it exists but is older.

  - As an alternative to *outputting* the source files of interest, you could perform a `Copy-Item` operation from the source to the destination dir. right there and then.

---

<sup>[1] The docs don't mention it as of this writing, but with `Compare-Object` it is sufficient to use a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) *directly* as a calculated property rather than providing it as the `Expression` entry of a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables); that is, `-Property { ... }` is the simpler alternative to `-Property @{ Expression = { ... } }`</sup>

Comment: Is there a more simple way if every file has a unique name? Like files names such as 2023-09-07-0001? There would be at most 3 files with that name, one destination, and one each source.

Comment: @FrigidFox: If the file names are unique in each collection, simply use `-Property Name, LastWriteTime`

Comment: I tried that. 
`$S1files, $S2files = $Source1Files, $Source2Files |  ForEach-Object {
    , ( Compare-Object -PassThru $_ $DestFiles -Property Name, LastWriteTime | 
        Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=' ) }`
It correctly removes files with the same lastWriteTime, but not the older files that are 8 months older.

Comment: The lastWriteTime of the older files 100% are older. Would the fact the default display format have anything to do with it? Ex: 09/07/2023 01:23:45 (new) and 01/07/2023 01:23:45 (old)

Comment: @FrigidFox, I'm unclear on your requirements. `-Property Name, LastWriteTime` compares by _both_ these properties, so files with the same name but different last-write times will be reported as differences. The `.LastWriteTime` property is of `[datetime]` and that is what is used for comparison, so _formatting_ doesn't enter the picture. Separately, the display formats shouldn't differ, and the example you're giving doesn't show a difference.

Comment: I am trying to grab the newest files. So comparing the LastWriteTime and only grabbing the latest ones.

Comment: @FrigidFox: Per your own attempt, you're only reporting the LHS (`-ReferenceObject`) difference objects, due to `Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='`, i.e. those from `$Source1Files` and `$Source2Files` - whether those are guaranteed to be the _newer_ ones only you can know - the comparison only tells you whether the property values _differ_.

Comment: Yes. Only grabbing the source files is what I am looking to do. How would I got about filtering for only files that are newer than what is on the destination?

Comment: Oh and a huge thank you for sharing your knowledge. Not only just informing me that what I wanted to do wasn't going to give me the results I wanted, but even your code that simplified a lot of what I had written previously. Your help has been much appreciated since programming isn't my background at all, and only started doing some powershell for about a year now.

Comment: So I am getting an error with Group-Object. A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.object[]'. I should note that the destination path has two additional folders in front of the path, and each uses a different drive letter.

Comment: An example of the file paths: Source N or M:\Target Folder\Folder 1\202309110001.pdf, Destination: O:\Department\Office\Target Folder\Folder 1\202309110001.pdf.

Comment: @FrigidFox, my bad: the syntax of the `Group-Object` call was broken, which I've fixed now (`& { $_; $DestFiles } | Group-Object -Property Name | ...`, i.e. the input objects must be passed via the pipeline). Please also see the alternative approach that I've added - as a description only (no code) - to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Thank you. All the errors have been cleared, but it partly failed. It correctly grabs a file from the source if it doesn't exist on the destination. It does not grab files that are newer on the source than the destination.

Comment: Sorry. I had a typo that VSCode wasn't catching.